# Tengo una Matriz en python, pero requiero extraer la información para quede solo 1 lista con la info que requiero

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, matriz

El problema es a partir de un Kata en CodeWars y llevo unos días pensando en una solución pero no llego a nada, el ejercicio consiste en que se ingresa una `lista` con el nombre de `sequence` y esta está constituida por unos números del 9 a 0, ej: `sequence = [3, 2, 1, 0, 5, 6, 4, 0, 1, 5, 3, 0, 4, 2, 8, 0]`.

Lo que hay que realizar es ordenar los números de menor a mayor en subconjunto y dejando el 0 al final lo que daría como resultado algo así `sequence = [1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 3, 5, 0, 2, 4, 8, 0]` y por ultimo esos subconjuntos hay que agruparlos de menor a mayor por el resultado de sus sumas que daría como resultado `sequence = [1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 3, 5, 0, 2, 4, 8, 0, 4, 5, 6, 0]`.

Ahora la solución que realicé para este ejercicio fue agrupar los subconjuntos en una lista a parte para poder ordenarlos y una vez estén dentro de la lista ordenar esta de menor a mayor consiguiendo el resultado esperado.

Pero el problema se presenta al validar las respuestas ya que el kata espera como respuesta una `lista` no  una `matriz`. lo que lleva a mi pregunta, como puedo extraer el valor de las sublistas para que quede solo 1 lista.

Adjunto código desarrollado por mi para dar solución al Kata así como el output y el output esperado.

```
sequence = [3, 2, 1, 0, 5, 6, 4, 0, 1, 5, 3, 0, 4, 2, 8, 0]
lista = [] 
sublista = []
for i in sequence:
    if i == 0: 
        sublista.sort()
        sublista.append(0)
        lista.append(sublista)
        sublista = []
    if i > 0:
        sublista.append(i)
lista.sort()
print(lista)
```

Este es el output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 0], [1, 3, 5, 0], [2, 4, 8, 0], [4, 5, 6, 0]]
```

y el output esperado es:

```
 [1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 3, 5, 0, 2, 4, 8, 0, 4, 5, 6, 0]
```

Agradezco sus consejos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dado que tienes la lista, puedes crear el resultado final simplemente usando `extend` en lugar de `append`.

La gracia de `extend` es que agrega los **elementos** de la sublista, no la sublista:

```
lista = [[1, 2, 3, 0], [1, 3, 5, 0], [2, 4, 8, 0], [4, 5, 6, 0]]
resultado = []
for sublista in lista:
    resultado.extend(sublista)
print(resultado)
```

produce:

```
[1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 3, 5, 0, 2, 4, 8, 0, 4, 5, 6, 0]
```

Comment: Me funcionó. Muchas Gracias.